# A Tic Tac Toe Game Made With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just finished creating a Tic Tac Toe game in Javascript, but now am wondering if there are ways I could improve upon the code I've written for it. Mind the lack of CSS here.

```js
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
const board = [
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
];
const players = ["X", "O"];
const playerWinBackgroundColor = "#00ff00";
const playerTieBackgroundColor = "#00ffff";

let cellsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(cells);
let winner = document.getElementById("winner");
let turn = document.getElementById("turn");
let player = getRandomPlayer();
let gameWon = false;

turn.innerText = `Player ${player}'s turn`;

cellsArray.forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (gameWon === false) {
      let row = cell.getAttribute("row");
      let col = cell.getAttribute("col");
      if (board[row][col] === 0) {
        board[row][col] = player;
        cell.innerText = player;
        if (checkWinner()) {
          winner.innerText = `Player ${player} wins!`;
          turn.innerText = "";
          gameWon = true;
          return;
        } else if (boardIsFull()) {
          winner.innerText = "Game is a tie!";
          turn.innerText = "";
          cellsArray.forEach(
            cell => cell.style.backgroundColor = playerTieBackgroundColor
          );
          return;
        }
        player = player == players[0] ? players[1] : players[0];
        turn.innerText = `Player ${player}'s turn`;
      }
    }
  });

  cell.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseEvents);
  cell.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseEvents);
});

function checkWinner() {
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 3; rowIndex++) {
    if (
      board[rowIndex][0] == player &&
      board[rowIndex][1] == player &&
      board[rowIndex][2] == player
    ) {
      cellsArray.filter(cell => {
        let colAttribute = cell.getAttribute("col");
        if (
          cell.getAttribute("row") == rowIndex &&
          (colAttribute == 0 || colAttribute == 1 || colAttribute == 2)
        ) {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = playerWinBackgroundColor;
        }
      });
      return true;
    }
  }

  for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 3; columnIndex++) {
    if (
      board[0][columnIndex] == player &&
      board[1][columnIndex] == player &&
      board[2][columnIndex] == player
    ) {
      cellsArray.filter(cell => {
        let rowAttribute = cell.getAttribute("row");
        if (
          cell.getAttribute("col") == columnIndex &&
          (rowAttribute == 0 || rowAttribute == 1 || rowAttribute == 2)
        ) {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = playerWinBackgroundColor;
        }
      });

      return true;
    }
  }

  let diagOne =
    board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player;
  let diagTwo =
    board[0][2] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player;

  if (diagOne || diagTwo) {
    if (diagOne) {
      cellsArray.filter(cell => {
        let rowAttribute = cell.getAttribute("row");
        let colAttribute = cell.getAttribute("col");
        if (
          (rowAttribute == 0 && colAttribute == 0) ||
          (rowAttribute == 1 && colAttribute == 1) ||
          (rowAttribute == 2 && colAttribute == 2)
        ) {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = playerWinBackgroundColor;
        }
      });
    } else if (diagTwo) {
      cellsArray.filter(cell => {
        let rowAttribute = cell.getAttribute("row");
        let colAttribute = cell.getAttribute("col");
        if (
          (rowAttribute == 2 && colAttribute == 0) ||
          (rowAttribute == 1 && colAttribute == 1) ||
          (rowAttribute == 0 && colAttribute == 2)
        ) {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = playerWinBackgroundColor;
        }
      });
    }
    console.log(board);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function resetGame() {
  gameWon = false;
  player = getRandomPlayer();
  winner.innerText = "";
  turn.innerText = `Player ${player}'s turn`;
  clearBoard();
  clearCellsArray();
}

function clearBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      board[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

function boardIsFull() {
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function clearCellsArray() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cellsArray.length; i++) {
    cellsArray[i].innerText = "";
    cellsArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}

function handleMouseEvents(event) {
  if (gameWon === false) {
    if (event.type === "mouseup") {
      event.target.style.borderStyle = "outset";
    } else if (event.type === "mousedown") {
      event.target.style.borderStyle = "inset";
    }
  }
}

function getRandomPlayer() {
  return players[(Math.random() >= 0.5) ? 1 : 0];
}
```

```css
#game * {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Consolas";
}

button {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px outset lightgrey;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <label id="winner"></label>
  <label id="turn"></label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" row="0" col="0"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="0" col="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="0" col="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" row="1" col="0"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="1" col="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="1" col="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" row="2" col="0"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="2" col="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="2" col="2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="resetGame()">Reset Game</button>
```

Comment: what is `cellsArray` in the tic-tac-toe game? I've never heard of that?

Answer (score 2):

### 1 HTML

#### 1.1 HTML Markup Validation

```html
<div id="game">
  <label id="winner"></label>
  <label id="turn"></label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" row="0" col="0"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="0" col="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="0" col="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" row="1" col="0"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="1" col="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="1" col="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" row="2" col="0"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="2" col="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" row="2" col="2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="resetGame()">Reset Game</button>
```

Your HTML Markup that you posted is invalid and would not pass the [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). My educated guess is that you only posted the parts of your `body` content, which for a Code Review is a **no-go**. Always paste the full code for review!

#### 1.2 Semantics

```html
<label id="winner"></label>
<label id="turn"></label>
```

A `label` is a semantic element to label an interactive element such as input and output elements.
In your case, you're not labeling anything. You use that element to output information.

As such an `<output>` element would be more appropriate to use!

```html
<div class="cell" row="0" col="0"></div>
<div class="cell" row="0" col="1"></div>
<div class="cell" row="0" col="2"></div>
```

Those cells are not just generic containers but interactive elements that you're supposed to click on. As such `<button>`s would be more appropriate here!

#### 1.3 `onclick` Attribute

```html
<button onclick="resetGame()">Reset Game</button>
```

You use an `onclick` attribute to trigger the reset function. In modern programming, you should split HTML, CSS, and JS always from each other for various reasons. One of them is an economic reason: **Maintenance**. You should always write code (at least in industrial standard) to be easily maintained and for other programmers to take over. As such you should use the `addEventListener` in JS button instead as otherwise, a function renaming would require to be fixed both in JS and HTML instead of just one place (JS).

### 2 CSS

#### 2.1 Grid Layout

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px outset lightgrey;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell" row="0" col="0"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="0" col="1"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="0" col="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell" row="1" col="0"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="1" col="1"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="1" col="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell" row="2" col="0"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="2" col="1"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="2" col="2"></div>
</div>
```

You are creating a **grid layout** here. We could argue that it is a table in which case you also should use `<table>`. There could be also an argument that it is a game board that has a table-like layout and does not contain strictly tabular data. In such case, you should use a CSS Grid:

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
}

.cell {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 2px outset lightgrey;
  /* can align the text to center */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell" row="0" col="0"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="0" col="1"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="0" col="2"></div>
  
  <div class="cell" row="1" col="0"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="1" col="1"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="1" col="2"></div>
  
  <div class="cell" row="2" col="0"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="2" col="1"></div>
  <div class="cell" row="2" col="2"></div>
</div>
```

#### 2.2 Responsivness

```css
#game * {
  font-size: 36px;
}

button {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

You use fixed `px` values for font sizes and spacing. This makes the game hardly responsive and will cause poor UI/UX on high-resolution screens or for users that require zoom.

You should use relative units such as `em` or `rem` here.

### 3 JS

#### 3.1 Element Lists

```js
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
let cellsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(cells);
cellsArray.forEach(cell => { ... });
```

You working here with an element list. Specifically you're working with a ***HTML Collection Object**. In the next step you convert the `object` to an `array`.
**Why are you doing it?** Because you want to use `forEach` as an iteration method instead of a `for` loop. `forEach` does not work with that kind of object:

```js
const LIST = document.getElementsByClassName('cell');
console.log(typeof LIST);

LIST.forEach(element => {
  element.textContent = 'test';
})
```

```html
<div class="cell" row="0" col="0"></div>
<div class="cell" row="0" col="1"></div>
<div class="cell" row="0" col="2"></div>
```

The smarter and easier approach to this kind of issue is to work with a more modern type of list, the **Node List**. All you need to do is to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`:

```js
const LIST = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
console.log(typeof LIST);

LIST.forEach(element => {
  element.textContent = 'test';
})
```

```html
<div class="cell" row="0" col="0"></div>
<div class="cell" row="0" col="1"></div>
<div class="cell" row="0" col="2"></div>
```

#### 3.2 `innerText` Method

The `innerText` method (good that you didn't use `innerHTML` here) has one major downside:
It requires the document to prepare which is time-consuming. Even though it is just milliseconds, it is still inefficient and it will scale up.

The efficient approach is the usage of the newer `textContent` method instead.

#### 3.3 `true`/`false` If-Statement

```js
if (gameWon === false) { ... }
```

While this `if` statement is not wrong and obviously works, it is unclean. `true` and `false` are boolean values while an `if` statement also looks for a boolean value. As such there is no need for a boolean comparison as you can simply just use the variable as a comparison. However, since you looking for a `false` boolean and not a `true` boolean you have to use `!` in front: `!gameWon`:

```js
let gameWon = false;

// expecting statement to be true 
if (!gameWon) {
  console.log('Statement "!gameWon" is true')
} else {
  console.log('Statement "!gameWon" is false')
}

// expecting statement to be false 
if (gameWon) {
  console.log('Statement "gameWon" is true')
} else {
  console.log('Statement "gameWon" is false')
}
```

#### 3.4 Custom `row` and `col` Attribute

while you could argue whether it is correct or incorrect to use a `col` and `row` attribute here I would state that it semantically isn't.
What you can use without any argument here are `data` attributes:

```js
const CELL = document.querySelector('.cell');
let row = CELL.dataset.row;
let col = CELL.dataset.col;

console.log(`Row: ${row}, Col: ${col}`);
```

```html
<div class="cell" data-row="0" data-col="1"></div>
```

#### 3.5 `if`/`else` Statement vs `switch` Statement

```js
if (checkWinner()) {
  winner.innerText = `Player ${player} wins!`;
  turn.innerText = "";
  gameWon = true;
  return;
} else if (boardIsFull()) {
  winner.innerText = "Game is a tie!";
  turn.innerText = "";
  cellsArray.forEach(
    cell => cell.style.backgroundColor = playerTieBackgroundColor
  );
  return;
}
player = player == players[0] ? players[1] : players[0];
turn.innerText = `Player ${player}'s turn`;
```

In the very worst case a `switch` will take as long as 2 `if` statements. In most cases, it is even faster than that. In any case, a `switch` statement will be faster than an `if` statement combined with an `else if` statement. The more statements are combined the larger the performance difference will be.

The whole block can be factorized with a `switch`- tatement as such (which IMHO is also more readable):

```js
switch (true) {
  case (checkWinner()):
    winner.innerText = `Player ${player} wins!`;
    turn.textContent = '';
    gameWon = true;
    break;
  case (boardIsFull()):
    winner.innerText = "Game is a tie!";
    turn.textContent = '';
    cellsArray.forEach(
      cell => cell.style.backgroundColor = playerTieBackgroundColor
    );
    break;
  default:
    player = player == players[0] ? players[1] : players[0];
    turn.innerText = `Player ${player}'s turn`;
}
```

#### 3.6 Styling through JS

Styling of a document should for various reasons, such as performance by caching and reusability, always be a task for CSS in modern programming!

**Disadvantages of the `style` JS method**:

- manipulates the style by using `inline-style` with the highest weight, which overwrites all other styles.
- cannot be cached (performance loss)
- Harder to maintain and debug, as the weight is hard to track
- Harder to read
- extend the required JS lines
- ...

The modern solution to apply styles is by using the `classList` method which adds, removes, or toggles a CSS class from the element.

##### 3.6.1 Add

With `classList.add()` you adding a class to an element:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.add('bg-color');
})
```

```css
.bg-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Add the class "bg-color" to the body</button>
```

##### 3.6.2 Remove

With `classList.remove()` you remove a class from an element:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.remove('bg-color');
})
```

```css
.bg-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-color">
  <button>Remove the class "bg-color" from the body</button>
</body>
```

##### 3.6.3 Toggle

With `classList.toggle()` you can apply a class to an element if it doesn't have it already. In case that the element already has that specific class, it will remove that class:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('bg-color');
})
```

```css
.bg-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle to apply/remove the class "bg-color" to/from the body</button>
```

You also have the option to add a second parameter with a clean or `if` statement to apply a class only if a certain condition is met:

```js
let gameWon = true;

// expected to be true and apply 
document.body.classList.toggle('bg-color', gameWon);

// expected to be false and not apply 
document.body.classList.toggle('border-color', !gameWon);
```

```css
.bg-color {
  background-color: red;
}

.border-color {
  border: 5px dashed blue;
}
```

### 3.7 Minor Logic Advice

There are a few parts of the code that could be solved in another way and which I would rate my students for.

#### 3.7.1 Swapping Player by Array

```js
const players = ["X", "O"];
player = player == players[0] ? players[1] : players[0];
```

Good job for using a ternary conditional operator here instead of an `if`/`else` statement. However there is a smarter way of solving it with the help of the modulus:

```js
const PLAYERS = ["X", "O"];
let player = 0;

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  player = (player + 1) % 2;
  console.clear();
  console.log(`Player ${PLAYERS[player]}'s turn`);
})
```

```html
<button>Swap Player</button>
```

It works by simple calculation where you always add 1 to the current player. Then you divide it by 2 and look for the remainder (modulus): `player = (player + 1) % 2`

> Start:
> player = 0
>
> Round 1:
> (0 + 1) % 2 = 1 (0, remains **1**)
>
> Round 2:
> (1 + 1) % 2 = 0 (1, remains **0**)

#### 3.7.2 Winning and Draw Logic

You should track the turns or rounds!

To win you need to have 3 in a row which requires that a player has at least done 3 moves. So the earliest turn where a player could win is at the end of round 5. Only then can the starting player achieve a win.

A draw can only appear at the end of round 9.

If you track the round then you do not have to check if all cells are filled because at the end of turn 9, they should all be filled!

Also, you can then limit the execution of the winning logic function as well as the draw function. You only run the winning check function at turn 5 or later and the draw function only at turn 9.

**Why is that important?**

Running functions costs computing power. In other words, time and performance. This might not matter much to you at this point but will help you to develop good habits and focus on performance. That is a very important skill to have if you develop more complex applications or games, especially for limited hardware such as mobile devices.

#### 3.7.3 Restart

The fastest way to restart a game, especially if you do not track wins and losses, is by simply reloading the document: `location.reload();`

Answer (score 1):

**Put More Structure in the Structure**

The `board` is just a lame Array leaving the user code to do all the work. Or maybe we're talking about `cellArray`, I don't know. Anyway,  Make it a useful object with methods. It will seem like "extra" work, but all the code is simple, easy to TEST, read, understand, and maintain. [By making coherent objects we naturally get decoupling.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3085285/463206)

Define `rows`, `columns`, and `diagonals`.  Then methods `rowWinner`, `columnWinner`, `diagonalWinner` will be very simple. Then user code to evaluate for a winner will shrink 90% or more.

```
function board = () {
  const board = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ];

  rows = [
    [board[0,0],board[0,1],board[0,2]]
    [board[1,0],board[1,1],board[1,2]]
    [board[2,0],board[2,1],board[2,2]]
  ];

  diagonals = [
    [board[0,0],board[1,1],board[2,2]]
    [board[1,2],board[1,1],board[0,2]]
  ];

  columns = [
    [board[0,0],board[1,0],board[2,0]]
    [board[0,1],board[1,1],board[2,1]]
    [board[0,2],board[1,2],board[2,2]]
  ];

 // one call to rule them all.
 winner = function(player) {
   return (rowWinner(player)    ||
           columnWinner(player) ||
           diagonalWinner(player)
          ) 
 }

 rowWinner (player) {
     let won = false
     board.rows.forEach(row) => {
       won = row.every(cell) => { cell === player} ? true : won
     return won
  }

} // board
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would separate the UI code from the game logic. You can make the whole game playable in the console by calling functions. Those functions indicate which cell is getting an X or O, and then check if there is a winner and who is the next player.

The whole UI is a separate module that calls the game functions, draws the resulting grid in the browser, and updates text messages.

That way you can focus on optimising the game logic without worrying about CSS attributes and such. Also, it will be much easier to change the UI afterwards.